# add and remove class of each div

Tags: jquery

I want to know if there's any way to add class 'active' to each div by interval of time but only one of them can have the 'active' class on the inverval on jquery like:

```
<div class="item active"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

And after some interval of time

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item active"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Then later...

```
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item active"></div>
```

I added something like this but is not what I want:

```
jQuery('.carousel-inner').mouseenter(function() {
  jQuery('.item').each(function(i) {
var $sh = jQuery(".item");
setInterval(function(){
    $sh.toggleClass("active");
}, 1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use either `setInterval` or `setTimeout` recursively. I prefer `setTimeout` recursively simply because this guarrantees the previous operation has completed before the next one begins.

```js
$(function () {
    
    var index = 1,
        max = $('.item').length;

    function setActive() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            index++;
            if(index > max) {
                index = 1;    
            }
            $('.item:nth-of-type(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
            setActive();
        }, 1500);
    }
    
    setActive();
    
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: green;
}
div.active {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item active"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

The previous code snippet is just an example. I'm not sure based on your post what the class does but the CSS should demonstrate the point of what you're trying to accomplish.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/jo29qa34/1/)**

Comment: thx, I add like that 
$(function () {
    
    var index = 1,
        max = $('.item').length;

    function setActive() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.active').removeClass('active');
            index++;
            if(index > max) {
                index = 1;    
            }
            $('div:nth-of-type(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
            setActive();
        }, 1500);
    }
    
    setActive();
    
});

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div.item').removeClass('active');
$('div.item:eq('+n+')' ).addClass('active');
```

where n would be the index of the item you want to add the active class to

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var i=0;

setInterval(function(){

            $(".item.active").removeClass("active");  
            $(".item:eq("+i+")").addClass("active");
            i++;
            if(i>=$(".item").length){
               i=0;
            }

},100);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wrj65opk/9/)